# SQL Server - Exporting a DateTime Value between servers changes value (time zone issue?)

Tags: .net, sql-server, datetime

**Here is how the export works**

1. .NET DataTable is created by a SQL Query
2. DataSet is serialized and sent via HTTP Request to an Importer
3. Importer Deserializes and performs a series of insert/updates; one per DataTable row

**Details**

- Exporting SQL Server is in the Eastern (US) Timezone
- Importing SQL Server is in the Central (US) Timezone

**The Problem**

- A datetime value is 1-3-2012 00:00:00 Eastern (midnight 1/3/12 Eastern)
- This value is exported through the previous mentioned mechanism
- When it is deposited to the destination (central) SQL Server, it has the value 1-2-2012 23:00:00 (11:00 PM the day before)

**The datetime value should not change from one server to the next. It needs to stay 1-3-2012 00:00:00.**

**What have I tried?**

- I have confirmed that the corresponding date values are indeed 1 hour off after re-running the export
- I have confirmed that an hour is not being subtracted by my code

  - Serialization occurs via the BinaryFormatter.Serialize function, with the DataSet itself going right in
  - Deserialization occurs via the BinaryFormatter.Deserialize function
  - A call to a stored procedure is made with one parameter per column in the DataTable. I have confirmed that there is a direct copy for the date value via the following code: `CMD.Parameters("@p" & col.ColumnName).Value = row(col.ColumnName)`
- I've analyzed the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for DateTime, but based upon my understanding (storing Date in the first 4 bytes, time in the last 4 bytes) there should never be a switch to a different day, even if each block of 4 bytes represents some relative offset from some base day or time
- I have confirmed that the moment the DataSet is deserialized in the new timezone, all datetimes have shifted 1 hour

This really feels like a timezone issue, but I can't figure out where it might be.

Comment: You can find the time difference between servers using GETUTCDATE() and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transferring a datetime from one SQL Server to another SQL Server via an `UPDATE` query across a Linked Server connection will preserve the date and time. 1/3/12 Midnight comes across as 1/3/12 Midnight, despite the time zone change.

However, by injecting the dates into a .NET Dataset, you subject the SQL DateTime variables to a data conversion to .NET DateTime.

The display of a DateTime varies by TimeZone. If you load the same bits in Boston as you do in California via the ToString() function, you will get two different results.

As a result, by the time this code is called, the damage is done

- `CMD.Parameters("@p" & col.ColumnName).Value = row(col.ColumnName)`

**To fix this problem**, you must either determine the time zone offset and adjust the value, or serialize to a safer format, thus avoiding the .NET DateTime, as mentioned by @competent_tech.

**References**

- [SQL Server DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)
- [.NET DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) - Scroll down to "Datetime Values" section

Answer (score 0):

One simple trick to try: serialize the date as a string rather than a .Net datetime type. This will remove any timezone issues.